# Object или параметризация?

Tags: java

Когда мы пишем класс, но не знаем с какими объектами будем работать (допустим храниить переменную) мы можем просто задать переменную типа Object. Тоже самое мы можем сделать используя параметризацию. Но! Говорят что лучше использовать параметризацию. Почему?

Comment: А что вы подразумеваете под параметризацией?

Comment: "Обобщение". Использование условного типа.

Comment: Ну так вы получаете контроль типов со стороны компилятора тогда.

Comment: по сути ничем, просто Object, возвращаемый методом, надо будет кастить к нужному, что может вызывать ошибки, например, - ClassCastException. При использовании обобщений компилятор предотвращает подобные ситуации

Comment: Тоесть разница будет состоять только в том, что компилятор будет проверять типы?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Здравствуйте, при использовании параметризации с условным типом `<?>` действительно наблюдается схожий с использованием `Object` эффект. Но параметризация позволяет использовать условные типы `<? extends Superclass>` и `<? super Subclass>`, что позволяет осуществлять контроль типов на этапе компиляции. В случае использования `Object` можно получить ошибку времени исполнения, что куда неприятнее.